Flutter app appears to shut down when launching another app
I'm working on a Flutter app where I'm experiencing an odd behavior where the app appears to shut down (Android Studio reporting Lost connection to device.) when launching an external app through url_launcher:
await launchUrl(Uri.parse("https://maps.google.com"));

This launches the Google Maps app as expected.
I have added a listener to see how the state changes when launchUrl() is invoked:
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
   log('Screen state changed to: $state');
}

When launchUrl() is invoked, I see the following in the Android Studio console:
[log] Screen state changed to: AppLifecycleState.inactive
[log] Screen state changed to: AppLifecycleState.hidden
[log] Screen state changed to: AppLifecycleState.paused
Lost connection to device.

The Google Maps app opens as expected, but if I hit the back button, I end up on the splash screen of the Flutter app in what appears to be a hanged state.
I'm on Android Studio Ladybug, 2024.2.1.
I'm debugging on a physical device running Android 10 connected with a USB cable.
Here is the flutter doctor output:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4169], locale en-SE)
    • Flutter version 3.24.1 on channel stable at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5874a72aa4 (7 weeks ago), 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
    • Engine revision c9b9d5780d
    • Dart version 3.5.1
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ted\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.32)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools
    • Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 version 16.11.34301.259
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] VS Code (version 1.94.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ted\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Mi A2 Lite (mobile) • 67630e470305 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Windows (desktop)   • windows      • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4169]
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome       • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.120
    • Edge (web)          • edge         • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 129.0.2792.65

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!


Can you update Flutter to latest (3.24.3) ? I see a fix flutter team provided to make this kind of errors more user-friendly and it's landed in 3.24.2. Maybe it'll help diagnose your case.

@Sameri11 Thanks for the tip, but seeing the same behavior with 3.24.3.

Maybe that's because googleMaps is quite heavy app and system just stops your flutter app to free up memory for Google Maps?

it really hard to tell what is cause of this issue. I think maybe because your device OS just terminate your app for memory like @Sameri11 said because Mi A2 Lite only got 3 gb of ram. Can your try with another newer device ?

Yeah, that's my main idea too. Currently looking into approaches for restoring state when it returns (restarts) the app if the OS closed it when the external app was launched. Thanks, guys.
